# Pandas groupby column A, then group together consecutive numeric values in column B

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, python-itertools

For the following dataframe:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"A":["HOX2A", "TRT1", "TRT1", "TRT1", "TRT1", "TP53", "TP53"], "B":[0,5,6,7,42, 1, 2], "val":["A", "T", "T", "G", "C", "A", "A"]})

    A       B  val
0   HOX2A   0  A
1   TRT1    5  T
2   TRT1    6  T
3   TRT1    7  G
4   TRT1   42  C
5   TP53    1  A
6   TP53    2  A
```

I need to group first by column A, then by values in column B that are in consecutive order.

The output should look like this:

```
HOX2A
B  val
0  A

TRT1
B  val
5  T
6  T
7  G

TRT1
B   val
42  C

TP53    
B  val
1  A
2  A
```

I tried the following, but it did not keep the sequential order of values in A and B:

```
import more_itertools as mit
import pandas as pd

regions = df.groupby("A")

var_list = []
for grp, data in regions:
    results = [list(zip(list(data.A), list(group)) for group in 
               mit.consecutive_groups(data.B.to_list())]
```

I found a few other similar questions on SO, but nothing that applied or worked for this particular need.

Comment: ```df.sort_values(by = 'B').groupby('A')``` will sort the values by B before the groupby. This will keep B in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Series which allows you to form consecutive groups where the diff is 1 within 'A':

```
s = df.groupby('A').B.apply(lambda x: x.diff().fillna(1).ne(1).cumsum())

for idx, gp in df.groupby(['A', s], sort=False):
    print(idx[0])
    print(gp,'\n')
```

#### Output:

```
HOX2A
       A  B val
0  HOX2A  0   A

TRT1
      A  B val
1  TRT1  5   T
2  TRT1  6   T
3  TRT1  7   G

TRT1
      A   B val
4  TRT1  42   C

TP53
      A  B val
5  TP53  1   A
6  TP53  2   A
```

Or store them in a dict: `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['A', s])))`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped :D!